# How To Pass GET Parameters To Laravel From With GET Method ?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

i'm stuck at this very basic form, that i could not accomplish, which i want to build a search form with an text input, and two select controls, with a route that accept 3 parameters, the problem that when the i submit the form, it map the parameters with the question mark, not the Laravel way,

### Markup

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'search', 'method' => 'GET'])}}
    <input type="text" name="term"/>
    <select name="category" id="">
        <option value="auto">Auto</option>
        <option value="moto">Moto</option>
    </select>
    {{ Form::submit('Send') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

### Route

```
    Route::get('/search/{category}/{term}', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

When i submit the form it redirect me to

```
search/%7Bcategory%7D/%7Bterm%7D?term=asdasd&category=auto
```

How can i pass these paramters to my route with the Laravel way, and without Javascript ! :D

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The simplest way is just to accept the incoming request, and pull out the variables you want in the Controller:

```
Route::get('search', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

and then in `SearchController@search`:

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function search()
    {
        $category = Input::get('category', 'default category');
        $term = Input::get('term', false);

        // do things with them...
    }
}
```

Usefully, you can [set defaults in `Input::get()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input) in case nothing is passed to your Controller's action.

[As joe_archer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298740/658210), it's not necessary to put these terms into the URL, and it might be better as a POST (in which case you should update your call to `Form::open()` and also your search route in routes.php - `Input::get()` remains the same)

Comment: Writing `Input` always specify namespace to which it belongs

Answer (score 28):

I was struggling with this too and finally got it to work.

routes.php

```
Route::get('people', 'PeopleController@index');
Route::get('people/{lastName}', 'PeopleController@show');
Route::get('people/{lastName}/{firstName}', 'PeopleController@show');
Route::post('people', 'PeopleController@processForm');
```

PeopleController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers ;
use DB ;
use Illuminate\Http\Request ;
use App\Http\Requests ;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

    public function processForm() {
        $lastName  = Input::get('lastName') ;
        $firstName = Input::get('firstName') ;
        return Redirect::to('people/'.$lastName.'/'.$firstName) ;
    }
    public function show($lastName,$firstName) {
        $qry = 'SELECT * FROM tableFoo WHERE LastName LIKE "'.$lastName.'" AND GivenNames LIKE "'.$firstName.'%" ' ;
        $ppl = DB::select($qry);
        return view('people.show', ['ppl' => $ppl] ) ;
    }
```

people/show.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="/people">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First name">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Notes:
I needed to pass two input fields into the URI.
I'm not using Eloquent yet, if you are, adjust the database logic accordingly.
And I'm not done securing the user entered data, so chill.
Pay attention to the "_token" hidden form field and all the "use" includes, they are needed.

PS: Here's another syntax that seems to work, and does not need the

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

.

```
public function processForm(Request $request) {
    $lastName  = addslashes($request->lastName) ;
    $firstName = addslashes($request->firstName) ;
    //add more logic to validate and secure user entered data before turning it loose in a query
    return Redirect::to('people/'.$lastName.'/'.$firstName) ;
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but you should never do queries this way, even if you don't wanna follow the MVC architecture, you should always be using Eloquent for your database queries.

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem. I need show url for a search engine

I use two routes like this

```
Route::get('buscar/{nom}', 'FrontController@buscarPrd');

Route::post('buscar', function(){

   $bsqd = Input::get('nom');    

   return Redirect::action('FrontController@buscarPrd', array('nom'=>$bsqd));

});
```

First one used to show url like we want

Second one used by form and redirect to first one

Answer (score 6):

So you're trying to get the search term and category into the URL?

I would advise against this as you'll have to deal with multi-word search terms etc, and could end up with all manner of unpleasantness with disallowed characters.

I would suggest POSTing the data, sanitising it and then returning a results page.

Laravel routing is not designed to accept GET requests from forms, it is designed to use URL segments as get parameters, and built around that idea.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to [msturdy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27298952/1090438) is using the [request helper method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request) available to you.

This works in exactly the same way, without the need to import the `Input` namespace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input` at the top of your controller.

For example:

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function search()
    {
        $category = request('category', 'default');
        $term = request('term'); // no default defined

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Router

```
Route::get('search/{id}', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

Controller

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

    public function search(Request $request){

        $id= $request->id ; // or any params

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to specify expected parameters in action signature, but pass them as arbitrary `GET` arguments. Use filters, for example:

Create a route without parameters:

```
$Route::get('/history', ['uses'=>'ExampleController@history']);
```

Specify action with two parameters and attach the filter:

```
class ExampleController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct($browser)
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('filterDates', array(
            'only' => array('history')
        ));
    }

    public function history($fromDate, $toDate)
    {
        /* ... */
    }

}
```

Filter that translates `GET` into action's arguments :

```
Route::filter('filterDates', function($route, Request $request) {
    $notSpecified = '_';

    $fromDate = $request->get('fromDate', $notSpecified);
    $toDate = $request->get('toDate', $notSpecified);

    $route->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate);
    $route->setParameter('toDate', $toDate);
});
```