# Formatting routes for get requests

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, get

So in my Laravel project I have routes foor requests, which look classically like

```
Route::get('edit/{user}', 'AdminUserController@getUser');
Route::post('delete', 'AdminUserController@deleteUser');
```

etc.
The problem is that I don't know how to pass variables via get request links. For example, when I pass some variable with my link, like

```
$.get("{{action('Admin\AdminUserController@editUser')}}", {user: id})
```

I get link that looks like

> /edit?user=123

And this format does not match with one written in roures.php, where just slash is mentioned. What should I do to make this work properly? Somehow make get request look like */edit/123* or rewrite something in routes?

P.S I know that I could simply use `$.get('/edit/'+id)`, but I strongly need it to be `{{action}}`!

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298426/how-to-pass-get-parameters-to-laravel-from-with-get-method

Comment: @ReeceCottam now I have, thank you, I will try to make something out of this!

Comment: No problem at all, Happy to help =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your route you should send id with url not saperately as data. it will be something like

```
url : "/edit/id",
```

or make your route as `Route::get('edit', 'AdminUserController@getUser');`
and edit the row of id equals to `$request->id;`