# can't get parameters from url

Tags: php, laravel, get

I'm trying to get parameters from url like this

```
domain/test?key=value
```

and in my Laravel route I defined it this way

```
Route::get('test', 'mController@index');
```

and in `index()` I'm doing this

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request -> query('key');
    echo $value;
}
```

but `$value` is empty and nothing is printed. What is wrong? It's not a duplicate of another question because my problem was from NGINX config file not the PHP code

Comment: Try `$request->get('key)`

Comment: What is returned when you `dd($request->all())`?

Comment: not working @KhalidDabjan

Comment: empty array @mbozwood

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Pass GET Parameters To Laravel From With GET Method ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298426/how-to-pass-get-parameters-to-laravel-from-with-get-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your nginx config and pass the arguments

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change url like this

   ```
   domain/test/value
   ```
2. Change route

   ```
   Route::get('test/{key}', 'mController@index');
   ```
3. Access variable like this

   ```
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
      $value = $request->key;
      return $value;
   }
   ```

Comment: The function would need to be declared with $key as a variable: `public function index($key)`. `$value` would then equal `$key`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $value = Input::get('key');
        echo $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $request as the function parameter and `$request->get('key)` to get the parameter.

You also can use `$_GET['key']` to get that parameter.

Comment: for the first one it's empty again and for the second one I'm getting `Undefined index: code` error

Comment: You can log the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to check the request values in your url